# how to add parameters to startup delayer

Tags: windows-7, automation

Startup delayer is an application that is used to delay the execution of applications at startup.
And I want to take advantage of this function so that the regular applications that I am opening would be automated. How can I use the parameters function so that I could choose what operating system I want to boot when virtual box is included in the startup delayer.
What website I would want to be automatically opened with google chrome.
What specific project will be opened in visual studio. And others.
And please enlighten me if this is not the exact function the parameters has to perform.
Please do tell me of other application that can do the things mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters have nothing to do with Startup Delayer itself, they are the same as you could have if you started the application from the command line. So if you know how to start VirtualBox and have it select the VM you want from the command line you put that in the parameters field. The same goes for Visual studio.

One thing you can do instead is this:

Instead of adding the application **add the file you want the application to open**

- Want it to open a webpage, create a shortcut and add that to Startup Delayer
- Want it to open a VS-project, add the `.sln` file to Startup Delayer